# How to fit a gaussian model on the overlapped area of two separate gaussians?

Tags: normal-distribution

Suppose I have two 1D Gaussians distribution with N(U1,S1) and N(U2,S2) where U is the mean and S is the standard deviation. Suppose if we draw these two Gaussians, they overlap on a interval.

Now my question is that: "How can I fit a single Gaussian on the overlapped area ?"

is it possible to write a simple function to do that? I want to implement it if possible to see the outcome. so any help on this would be appreciated.

More information:

I want the final Gaussian distribution to have values only in the overlapped area and zero elsewhere.

Comment: Since Gaussians are supported on the whole real line, any two gaussians will overlap for the whole real line. I think you'll find that for $s_1,s_2$ 'small' and $|\mu_1 - \mu_2|$ 'large' it won't make a lot of sense to consider a single gaussian to fit for both

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: Think about the definition of a gaussian curve. There are no boundaries for where they are supported, so any value on the entire real line is acceptable as an input. Because of this, there is no finite region where they overlap

Comment: what if we suppose a truncated version where the Gaussian distributions are zero. [finite value in an interval]